# Significance of Low Variance Components of PCA for Lower-Dimensional Clustering

Tags: clustering, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I'm trying to apply PCA to reduce my fairly high dimensional dataset (~140 dimensions) down to 2-3 dimensions, for the explicit purposes of building an unsupervised clustering model that can be visualised. After applying normalization (Z score) and centering, I find that the 'explained' output of the first principal components is quite low. The first PC accounts for 40% of the variance, second 9% etc. etc., and even 10 PCs still only accounts for 75% of the total variance.

I'm aware that not having high variance in the first few PCs isn't necessarily a *bad* thing, and that I can try to look at other methods of lower dimensional embedding, but I just wanted to know if this means it would not be a *'good'* idea to try and build a clustering model from the first 2-3 PCs based on these results for PCA.

Comment: It *really* depends on the context of your data. I've seen social science that is okay with PCAs that have 20-30% variance in the 1st PCA. Some domains want 90%+ in the first few components.

Comment: Sure, my context is a Human Activity Recognition system, so ideally I'm looking for low-dimensional clusters that can correspond to different types of physical activity (a cluster for flat walking, a cluster for traversing up stairs, a cluster for traversing down stairs etc.). From that perspective, the clustering "accuracy" is quite important to me, so I would guess that my situation would be in the latter of your examples rather than the former.

Comment: Do you have codes you're trying to match for each of the observations? If so, it might be useful to plug the first few PCAs into the model and see how accurate it is. If you're data set is large enough, you could very reasonable use the first 10is PCAs in a Random Forest, SVM, logistic (well, multinomial) regression. In my limited experience, different types of dimensionality reduction may give you slightly different output, but won't radically change  amount of variance you're clustering. In short, your model is VIOLATING any rules, so I'd give it a shot.